# Samba domain controller sysvol authentication issue

Tags: debian, group-policy, samba, access-control-list, windows-10

Samba 4.2.10, Debian 8, Windows 10 workstations.
I recently rejoined one of machines to domain. Authentication works fine, and lets me login to the system, however it does not apply GPOs. From new machine I can navigate to sysvol share using \\SERVERNAME\sysvol, but not using \\FQDN\sysvol (prompts for credentials, but never authorizes correctly). This issue gets even more bizarre because machines already joined to domain can logon, and apply polices correctly.

I've tried samba-tool ntacl sysvolreset and sysvolcheck but without any success.
I have no clue what should be investigated in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not Samba related issue. It looks like previous compilations of windows 10 had bugs, probably UNC hardening being enabled by default.

In my case raised exception in Event viewer was (Event id 1058 error code 65).

Newer builds of Windows 10 pro (1607) up from October 2016 applies GPOs without any problems.